# Why this variable's scope is set to private?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am studying Parallel Programming from Peter Pacheco's book. On OpenMP chapter, I got confused with a simple example, which transforms odd-even transposition sort to OpenMP.

I can understand how this works and how directives are placed, but I can't seem to understand why phase's scope is set to private.

I am pasting a self written version of code from the book. Functions signature is `void omp_transposition_sort(double *list, int len)`

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(thread_count) \
        shared(list, len) private(i, phase) {
        for(int phase = 0; phase < len, phase++) {
            if(phase % 2 == 0) {                    // even phase
                #pragma omp for
                for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {     // compare 0 with 1, 2 with 3
                    if (list[i - 1] > list[i]) 
                        swap(list, i - 1, i);
                }
            } else {                                // odd phase
                #pragma omp for
                for(int i = 1; i < len - 1; ++i) {  // compare 1 with 2, 3 with 4
                    if(list[i] > list[i + 1])
                        swap(list, i, i + 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Why the author felt the need to explicitly set phase as a private variable  when `#pragma for` is called for each unique phase value?

Comment: Not having read the book, this is only a guess, but in most concurrent programming, shared state is bad, so privatizing the variable gives people less temptation to fiddle with it.

Comment: My guess is that the intentions is for each thread to have a their own `phase` variable for the even/odd check.

Comment: If the author began with c89, where the parallel loop counter might be defined outside the parallel, as the quoted method is disallowed, the private    clause would confirm the special openmp default for this situation.  Each thread must have distinct values to avoid race.

Comment: @tim18 But inner for loops are called after phase is checked serially and they don't read/write phase directly. Phase is controlled by serial code